# How to Block Key Board input in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to block the key board input when the form starts, but it is not working, please check my code:

```
Public Class Form2

   Public Declare Function BlockInput Lib "User32" (ByVal fBlock As Integer) As Integer

   Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

   End Sub

   Private Sub Panel1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint

   End Sub

   Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

       Dim name As String
       name = "12345"
       If (name = TextBox1.Text) Then
           Me.Close()
       End If
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

       TextBox1.Visible = True
       TextBox1.Focus()

   End Sub

   Private Sub TextBox2_Click_1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.MouseClick
       BlockInput(1)
   End Sub

   Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

   End Sub
End Class`
```

Comment: Do you need to globally block input or just for the textboxes?

Comment: Yes i want to block key board inputs globally

Comment: You're going to need a keyboard hook. That single function call won't cut it.

Comment: please tell how can i do that

Comment: @rayees Do you *really* want to block keyboard inputs globally? If so, please explain why - it's generally not the right approach and there will be a better way. For example, if you are building a Kiosk style application, check out [Windows Kiosk Mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/itpro/windows/manage/set-up-a-device-for-anyone-to-use) instead...

Comment: I am building an examination system, so when the exam starts the key board input should be disabled, to block any unwanted activity using the key board short cut keys.

Comment: That won't do. They could still use the on-screen keyboard. Utilize Kiosk Mode or [**Desktops**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681928(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I used "groupbox.enabled = False" in order to stop program users from editing anything within the groupbox on my form. You can then enable the groupbox again providing certain conditions are met. Another method I've used in my programming for VB.net was setting the read-only property (I used to to auto-populate the system date to prevent users from entering false dates) I don't know if either of those methods might help you?